# XMPP roster retrieving

Tags: java

What is meant by this ?

```
for (RosterEntry r : entries)
```

here "entries" is collection of RosterEntrys like this,

```
Collection<RosterEntry> entries;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look up some basic java tutorials.  This is referred to as a [foreach](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) loop.

This has nothing to do with XMPP or ejabberd as the original tags suggested.